# React Context. how to avoid "Cannot read properties of undefined" error before having a value

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React, and trying to build a photo Album with a a modal slider displaying the image clicked (on a different component) in the first place.

To get that, I set `<img src={albums[slideIndex].url} />` dynamically and set `slideIndex` with the `id`of the `img`clicked , so the first image displayed in the `modal slider` is the one I clicked.

The problem is that before I click in any image `albums[slideIndex].url`is obviously undefined and I get a `TypeError :cannot read properties of undefined`

How could I solve that?

I tried with data checks with ternary operator, like `albums ? albums[slideIndex].url : "no data"`, but doesn't solve it.

Any Ideas? what i am missing?

this is the component where I have the issue:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AlbumContext } from "../../context/AlbumContext";
import AlbumImage from "../albumImage/AlbumImage";
import "./album.css";
import BtnSlider from "../carousel/BtnSlider";


function Album() {
  const { albums, getData, modal, setModal, clickedImg } =
    useContext(AlbumContext);
  console.log("clickedImg id >>", clickedImg.id);

  
useEffect(() => {
    getData(); //-> triggers fetch function on render
  }, []); 

  ///////////
  //* Slider Controls
  ///////////

  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(clickedImg.id);
  console.log("SlideINDEx", slideIndex ? slideIndex : "no hay");
  const nextSlide = () => {
    if (slideIndex !== albums.length) {
      setSlideIndex(slideIndex + 1);
    } else if (slideIndex === albums.length) {
      setSlideIndex(1);
    }
    console.log("nextSlide");
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    console.log("PrevSlide");
  };

  const handleOnclick = () => {
    setModal(false);
    console.log(modal);
  };
  return (
    <div className="Album_Wrapper">
      <div className={modal ? "modal open" : "modal"}>
        <div>
          <img src={albums[slideIndex].url} alt="" />
          <button className="carousel-close-btn" onClick={handleOnclick}>
            close modal
          </button>
          <BtnSlider moveSlide={nextSlide} direction={"next"} />
          <BtnSlider moveSlide={prevSlide} direction={"prev"} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Album_GridContainer">
        {albums &&
          albums.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <AlbumImage
                className="Album_gridImage"
                key={index}
                image={item}
              />
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Album;
```

THis is my AlbumContext :

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const AlbumContext = createContext();

export const AlbumContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState();

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [clickedImg, setClickedImg] = useState("");

  const showImg = (img) => {
    setClickedImg(img);
    setModal(true);
    console.log(clickedImg);
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos"
      );
      const obj = await response.json();
      console.log(obj);
      setAlbums(obj);
    } catch (error) {
      //   console.log(error.response.data.error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  console.log(`Albums >>>`, albums);

  return (
    <AlbumContext.Provider
      value={{ albums, getData, showImg, modal, setModal, clickedImg }}
    >
      {children}
    </AlbumContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: What's `getData` and `AlbumContext`?

Comment: ```getData```is the function that triggers the fetch function on my context, and ```AlbumContext```is my context provider. 
That is working. I fetch the images and get them in my component with ```albums```
Should I paste also those components?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like they're a part of the problem

Comment: edited with the AlbumContext. 

Although not sure if there might be the problem. 
After I click, I do get the values. 
The problem is at the first render.

Comment: is your ```albums``` is array??

Comment: an array of Objects, yeah.

And ```clickedImg```contains all the information from the  single img clicked : description, Url, id, etc...

Comment: ok wait i will answer on answer section

Comment: can you try one of these, `<img src={albums[slideIndex]?.url} alt="" />` or `{(album && slideIndex) && <img src={albums[slideIndex].url} alt="" />}`

Comment: the second works 
{(album && slideIndex) && <img src={albums[slideIndex].url} alt="" />}
Thanks!

Comment: @Iala , any idea what would be the logic with ```nextSlider``` to go back to the 1st img after the last, and to the last after the first?
```albums.lenght``` has 1 element less than .ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `clickedImg` starts out as the empty string:

```
const [clickedImg, setClickedImg] = useState("");
```

And in the consumer, you do:

```
const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(clickedImg.id);
```

So, it takes the value of `clickedImg.id` on the first render - which is `undefined`, because strings don't have such properties. As a result, both before and after fetching, `slideIndex` is `undefined`, so after fetching:

```
albums ? albums[slideIndex].url : "no data"
```

will evaluate to

```
albums[undefined].url
```

But `albums[undefined]` doesn't exist, of course.

You need to figure out what slide index you want to be in state when the fetching finishes - perhaps start it at 0?

```
const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);
```

Comment: of course...how didn't think of that! 
Thanks! 

How should I reorganize then? 
Maybe move ```const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);```to my Context and export the variable to the  component? 
Better other way?

Comment: I don't know what sort of logic you're trying to implement by linking the `clickedImage.id` with the `slideIndex`. If you want them to be the same all the time, call `setSlideIndex` every time `clickedImage` changes.

Comment: I changed the initial state of the slideIndex to 0 , but i get a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')....getting desperate :D

Comment: Sounds like you're not testing that `albums` actually exists first - make sure that it exists (like you're doing in your code originally) before trying to access properties on it.

Comment: the logic  was thought at the beggining when i was mapping through ```albums```, to go back to the 1st img after reaching the last, but i guess now it has no sense. 
I will remove it.

Comment: something like this ? ```{albums ? <img src={albums[slideIndex].url} alt="" /> : "nothing"} ```

it looks like it is working! 
thanks!!

(sorry...too long hours with this)

Comment: May I ask you one very last thing? 

If I make  ```nextSlide =() =>{setSlideIndey(slideIndex+1)} ```what the logic would be to turn back to the first, when it reaches the last of the Array?

Comment: `setSlideIndex((slideIndex+1) % array.length)` where `array` is the array you're interested in?

Answer (score -1):

maybe because your code for checking `albums` is empty or not is wrong and its always return `true` condition so change your code to this:

```
<div className="Album_GridContainer">
        {albums.length > 0 &&
          albums.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <AlbumImage
                className="Album_gridImage"
                key={index}
                image={item}
              />
            );
          })}
      </div>
```

change `albums` to `albums.length`

Comment: still throws the same error. 
it is before that check (or so I think)

If I comment out ```<img src={albums[slideIndex].url} alt="" />```
The table of images renders without a problem.